# Struggle with QGIS C++ API

Tags: c++, qgis

I'm trying to create a simple application using QGIS SDK. But currently, I'm stuck with API at very beginning stage.
belows are the env.

Windows 7

MSVC 2015

QGIS SDK (downlaod by OSGeo4w) include:
    qgis-dev(3.2.3)
    Qt5(5.9)

[here is the OSGeo4w directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPofS.jpg)

[here is the OSGeo4w/app directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqhKM.jpg)

And start by create an empty project, property settings:

C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include\QtCore
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include\QtGui
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include\QtWidgets
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include\QtXml
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\include
C:\OSGeo4W\include
```

Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\lib
```

Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

```
qtmaind.lib
Qt5Cored.lib
Qt5Guid.lib
Qt5Widgetsd.lib
qgis_core.lib
qgis_app.lib
qgis_gui.lib
```

The test code is quite simple:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <qgsapplication.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QgsApplication a(argc, argv, true);
 //  QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("C:/path/to/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", true);
 //  QgsApplication::initQgis();
 //  ImageViewer w; 
 //  w.show();

     return a.exec(); 
}
```

however, errors occured when I build it,

(1)no instance of constructor "QgsMapUnitScale::QgsMapUnitScale" matches the argument list  (qgsrendercontext.h)

(2)"M_PI": undeclared identifier (qgsabstractgeometry.h)

[here is the build error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNCV9.jpg)

Could anyone give me a suggestion?I have some difficulties to understand how the API should work and there is really few doc. and resource about 
QGIS C++ developement on internet, even on QGIS offical website.

I appreciate any help, thanks.